# Pulse audio error module-echo-cancel.c not found

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I am trying to activate echo cancel module. I added the line `load-module module-echo-cancel`, but when I try to restart `pulseaudio` now I get this error:

```
E: [pulseaudio] module-echo-cancel.c: Master source not found
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-echo-cancel" (argument: ""): initialization failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
```

Previously I used antergos and didn't have any issue with `pulseaudio`.

After reinstalling `pulseaudio` now I started to get this error:

```
cannot cancel echo between a sink and its monitor
```